# how to animate to 2nd tab when 1st tab recyclerview item is clicked from adapter?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have been looking for a solution past 2 days and yet no solution worked. So I had to use Intent to restart the activity when item of recyclerview is clicked. Below is the code:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Context context = view.getContext();

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
            SharedData.setSelectedCategory(category.getName());
            intent.putExtra("category", category.getName());
            context.startActivity(intent);
            ((MyActivity) context).finish();
        }
    });
```

and then used below code in the activity to select the 2nd tab like this.

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, false);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

While this works but I still would like to use slide animation to load 2nd tab when 1st tab recyclerview item is clicked. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use broadcast from onClick to activity, then in an activity you can do something like this`viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);`

**In Activity**

```
 public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "BROADCAST_ACTION";

BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction() != null &&
                intent.getAction().equals(BROADCAST_ACTION)) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(
            MainActivity.this).registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(BROADCAST_ACTION));
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
}
```

**In adapter onClick**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.BROADCAST_ACTION);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Try below code in your activity

```
viewPager.setAnimation(your_custom_animation);
```

Comment: Could you please give me some sample code? I don't know much about broadcast. I guess I will learn in soon.

Comment: Sorry for late reply but it's still loading old way. I did what you suggested.

Comment: do you want to use custom slide animation for tab selection ?

Comment: yes same animation when I click "TAB2" from "TAB1".